# How to initialise a Java enum using an inner static final field?

Tags: java, enums

I am designing a text-only videogame with two characters not often seen together, yet very much alike in heart and disposition.

My problem is that I don't know how to initialise an `enum` constant through a constructor using a static final inner constant. Otherwise the game is good to go. ;)

Here's the dilemma:

1. The enum constants must be defined in the first line of the enum, if I am not mistaken
2. The first line can't refer to anything coming after it (i.e. "cannot reference a field before it is defined")

How do I resolve this catch-22?

Here some sample code released from the game under non-disclosure agreement:

```
enum ValiantHeroWithPrincessSavingTendencies {

  SUPERMARIO(TYPICAL_QUOTE_FROM_MARIO), ZELDA(TYPICAL_QUOTE_FROM_ZELDA);

  private String aPreparedQuotePurportedToBeSpontaneousAlmostImpulsive;

  public String getQuoteUnderStressfulCircumstances() {
    return aPreparedQuotePurportedToBeSpontaneousAlmostImpulsive;
  }

  private ValiantHeroWithPrincessSavingTendencies(String quote) {
    aPreparedQuotePurportedToBeSpontaneousAlmostImpulsive = quote;
  }

  private static final String TYPICAL_QUOTE_FROM_ZELDA = "Have at ya!";
  private static final String TYPICAL_QUOTE_FROM_MARIO = "We, wagliu'!";
}
```

I am trying to initialise SUPERMARIO using TYPICAL_QUOTE_FROM_MARIO but I haven't defined TYPICAL_QUOTE_FROM_MARIO yet. Moving the private static final field before SUPERMARIO is illegal, I think.

Comment: I'd say, just do it the other way round. But you made those fields `private`. How can they ever be useful? Whats the functional requirement / design consideration behind this all?

Comment: Why not putting the strings inside the enum constructor instead of having a useless (private) static final field for that? Like this: `SUPERMARIO("Have at ya!"), ...`

Comment: @BalusC ... but it's _Object-oriented_ :-)

Comment: If I have a const value, I always represent it as a `static final`, don't you? If a const value is of no use beyond the class, I always mark it as private. Less clutter when I am client of my own code and the visibility hides the constants for me. Sounds fair?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only viable options are to either a) move your constants to another class or b) just put your constants directly into the value initializers.

If you move your constants, you can make the class a static class in the enum:

```
enum ValiantHeroWithPrincessSavingTendencies {
  SUPERMARIO(Quotes.TYPICAL_QUOTE_FROM_MARIO),
  ZELDA(Quotes.TYPICAL_QUOTE_FROM_ZELDA);

  private String aPreparedQuotePurportedToBeSpontaneousAlmostImpulsive;

  public String getQuoteUnderStressfulCircumstances() {
    return aPreparedQuotePurportedToBeSpontaneousAlmostImpulsive;
  }

  private ValiantHeroWithPrincessSavingTendencies(String quote) {
    aPreparedQuotePurportedToBeSpontaneousAlmostImpulsive = quote;
  }

  private static class Quotes {
    private static final String TYPICAL_QUOTE_FROM_ZELDA = "Have at ya!";
    private static final String TYPICAL_QUOTE_FROM_MARIO = "We, wagliu'!";
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this one! Let's see if anybody can do better but I am already typing this into my VideoGameEditor... let's see if I can get a few hours of fun by saving some princesses..

Comment: Why bother for stuff that's going to be local to the enum only?  This is excess complexity for no good reason.

Comment: @JimGarrison You may want to reuse strings. The "Have at ya!" string is also appropriate to certain grail-seeker-destroyers ;)

Comment: Because I have a convention I want to respect: no "magic numbers" and no sprinkling of String literals like confetti here and there.

Comment: @Brian It's all private.  This is OO rigor and complexity for its own sake, and the "benefit" is dubious.  If the strings were not private to the enum, then they would belong in their own external class/interface and this question wouldn't even exist.

Comment: @JimGarrison: what if you had static analysis tools helping you respect the convention where it makes sense and all of a sudden you need to "SuppressWarnings" of that sort, say with an Annotation, just because this particular case is quirky because of the way Java handles `enums` and their first line. I think it is the `enum` syntax being too rigid here! With a convention it could pick up the ENUM initialisations from anywhere... Anyway, I don't think it's so cut-and-dried here.

Answer (score 6):

You can just access them via class name:

```
enum ValiantHeroWithPrincessSavingTendencies {
    SUPERMARIO(ValiantHeroWithPrincessSavingTendencies.TYPICAL_QUOTE_FROM_MARIO),
    ZELDA(ValiantHeroWithPrincessSavingTendencies.TYPICAL_QUOTE_FROM_ZELDA);

    ...

    private static final String TYPICAL_QUOTE_FROM_ZELDA = "Have at ya!";
    private static final String TYPICAL_QUOTE_FROM_MARIO = "We, wagliu'!";
}
```

It's simplier than Brian's solution

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised this works around the compiler error. However, this only works for constants that are inlined at compile time (primitives and Strings); otherwise, the constant is dereferenced when initializing the enum value before the constant has been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The private static final constants are local to the enum; just code them in the instance definitions. After that point they can be accessed internally from the `aPreparedQuotePurportedToBeSpontaneousAlmostImpulsive` variable.

Comment: That's very pragmatic. But say I has a 1M lines' project and wanted to run static analysis on it to detect hard-coded literals (a bit like "FindBugs"? or some "CheckStyle"?)... all of a sudden I have to break the convention just because of the quirky way `enums` treat the "first line"? Hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

You could always do something hacky like this:

```
public enum Derp
{
    SOMETHING(),
    SOMETHINGELSE();

    private String herp;

    public static final String A = "derp", B = "derp2";

    public String getHerp()
    {
        return herp;
    }

    static
    {
        SOMETHING.herp = A;
        SOMETHINGELSE.herp = B;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow... that's hacky. I would have not thought of that... interesting!

Comment: Does this not work or something? I tested it and it works fine.

Comment: If a person did not want to eat, you'd stop feeding them. You'd not cut their stomach open and shove food into their stomach.
Then, why on earth, would you do this to an enum?